# Unity3D: C# - Can't seem to handle single/double/ hold touches correctly

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, touch

Using Unity3D 2018.2

*Trying to get Single tap, Double tap, and Hold tap.*

**Problems having:**

**Single Tap:** Sometimes won't register my single tap

**Double Tap:** Gets called 8 times every time I double Tap my device

**Triple Tap:** Double Tap gets called 10 times then Triple gets called 9 times

Here is my code, please your help would be appreciated on such a simple task I can not get right, new to C# and Unity

```
private void handleTouchTypes()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {

        float tapBeginTime = 0;
        float tapEndedTime = 0;

        //  Touches Began
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            tapBeginTime = Time.time;
        }

        //  Touches Ended
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            tapEndedTime = Time.time;

            //  Single Touch: for 0.022f of a Second
            if (touch.tapCount == 1 && ((tapEndedTime - tapBeginTime) < 0.03f))
            {
                Debug.Log("Single Touch");
            }

            //  Hold Touch: within half a second .5f to 1f
            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && touch.deltaPosition.magnitude < 0.02f && (tapEndedTime - tapBeginTime) >= 0.5f && (tapEndedTime - tapBeginTime) <= 1f)
            {
                Debug.Log("Holding Touch");
            }
        }

        if (touch.tapCount == 2)
        {
            //  Double Tap
            Debug.Log("Double Tap");
        }
        if (touch.tapCount >= 3)
        {
            //  Triple Tap
            Debug.Log("3 Touches and/or more");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few different things amiss here.

1) You're calling

```
    float tapBeginTime = 0;
    float tapEndedTime = 0;
```

at the start of each Touch element. Meaning your check for

```
(tapEndedTime - tapBeginTime) < 0.03f
```

will never pass, because `tapBeginTime` will have been reset to `0` by the point you set `tapEndedTime = Time.time;`.

If you want to track these times on a per-touch basis, I'd suggest creating a dictionary that maps the touches' `fingerId`s to their starting times. You don't need to record the `tapEndedTime` per touch, as it should suffice as a local variable calculated as needed.

2) I'm not a 100% sure on this, but you may also need to check `if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)` in addition to the `if (touch.tapCount == 2)` check, for accurate results. I know I've personally had issues not explicitly checking so in the past.

3) You're also doing a `if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)` check *inside* an `if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)` block. I'll let you figure this one out :)

I hope these points help you figure some of the immediate issues out. Once you've solved these surface issues, I suggest you explore ways to optimise your resulting code even further.
Good luck!